# "You are not the owner" when trying to copy files to a flash drive

Tags: nautilus, permissions, flash

While upgrading to 14.04 my PC lost power. Then I couldn't boot at all. I used a flash drive and then ran a check on the file system. Now I can see all the files I want to recover even though I can't boot to the drive. When I try to copy them to another flash drive it says I don't have ownership.

I tried what I could find in other posts but they didn't work. One was the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> then `gksu nautilus`, but then it just shows me a picture with gears and I can't seem to do anything after that. What I need to do is copy all of my files at the same time to a separate flash drive... then I will do a clean install of 14.04.

Comment: accumulator too strong ?! - electricity vaccum ?! - means shadow-electricity ?! - now is time to rest ... I need sleep. good night.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mount flash drive & device hard disk
2. Open a terminal and do the copy with root permissions.
   `sudo cp -R /media/YOUR_HARD_DISK /media/YOUR_FLASH_DRIVE`. *Theorically* you shouldn't be asked for any password. If you don't know mountpoints' names, you could run `cat /etc/mtab` and search for your partition.
3. You can also become owner of the files (I wouldn't recommend this) by typing `chown -R $USER /media/YOUR_HARD_DISK`. Then you should be able to copy files using the file manager.
4. You can also give everyone reading access to the files. Type `chmod -R a+x /media/YOUR_HARD_DISK`

Hopes this helps.
Giacomo

Comment: It shows this: gvfsd-fuse /run/user/999/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu 0 0
/dev/sda1 /media/ubuntu/263fca17-d053-4b17-9299-2411141b2dc4 ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
/dev/sda6 /media/ubuntu/7df673f9-b111-4f13-ac0e-4cefbd335e0a ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/ubuntu/PENDRIVE vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=999,gid=999,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2 0 0
sda1 is the partition I need to copy files from. I don't want to copy everything from the drive, I just need permission to copy my files.

Comment: Ok, you could try to change permissions to the files with `sudo chmod -R a+x /media/ubuntu/263fca17-d053-4b17-9299-2411141b2dc4`,so that everyone should be able to read these files. BTW, have you tried to type `sudo nautilus` in a terminal? The command should open a root file manager window...